# What goes into main function?

Tags: c++, coding-style, program-entry-point

I am looking for a best practice tip of what goes into the main function of a program using c++. Currently I think two approaches are possible. (Although the "margins" of those approaches can be arbitrarily close to each other)

1: Write a "Master"-class that receives the parameters passed to the main function and handle the complete program in that "Master"-class (Of course you also make use of other classes). Therefore the main function would be reduced to a minimum of lines.

```
#include "MasterClass.h"
int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
MasterClass MC(args, argv);
}
```

2: Write the "complete" program in the main function making use of user defined objects of course! However there are also global functions involved and the main function can get somewhat large.

I am looking for some general guidelines of how to write the main function of a program in c++. I came across this issue by trying to write some unit test for the first approach, which is a little difficult since most of the methods are private.

Comment: Usually argc is written instead of args. argc being a count of the number of arguments

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Why would you have one master class? What is its *single* area of responsibility?

"Master" or "application" classes tend to become big blobs that do way too many different things. Ultimately, what's the point? What did it buy you?

Why not use the **main** function to provide this **main** functionality? Define the high-level application lifecycle in `main`. It takes some command line arguments and parses them (preferably by delegating this out to another function or class), and then it calls some setup functionality, and then it might enter some kind of main loop, before doing some cleanup. All in all, this might give you a main function of perhaps 10-15 lines, but probably not more than that. It should delegate out to other classes and functions as much as possible. so `main` itself is kept short and sweet, but still has a purpose.

Putting this kind of super high-level flow in `main` means it's easy to find, because `main` is your starting point anyway. It is where you're going to start looking if you want to understand the code. So put in it what a reader wants to know when trying to understand the code.

Sure, you could take all that and put it in a "main class", and you'd have gained absolutely nothing, other than satisfying all the Java-luddites out there who feel that "everything must be in a class".

Comment: +1 if only for argument parsing. If one wishes to write "modular" code, then one must decouple the argument parsing (one interface among others) from the actual code, and use an appropriate structure to gather all those "settings". Note that argument parsing could also encompass the use of environment variables, since most of the times they are used to setup default. Then it's the trivial setup/loop until done/cleanup high-level view.

Comment: "Ultimately, what's the point?" Although not demonstrated here, it can provide dependency injection. Instead of having code that writes to `std::cout`, for example, the `Master` class **associates-with-a** `standardOutput` stream, a `std::ostream`. The `main()` function creates a `Master` object with `std::cout` for that association, but unit tests can use a `std::ostringstream`. It then becomes easy to unit test behavioural requirements such as "if the command-line is faulty, the program must write an error message to its standard eror output stream".

Comment: @Raedwald: why do you need a master class for that? Why can't `main` just create the appropriate `std::ostream` and then pass it to all the classes and functions it delegates out to? It doesn't need the master class for that.

Comment: But you did hit on a valid point by emphasizing that one sentence. "What's the point" was meant as an actual question, not just a rhetorical "there is no point". It is something you should ask yourself, because in some cases, there *might* be a point to creating a master class. I'm just saying that *often*, it's nothing more than an exercise in Java-think, and creating needless layers of indirection. And if you can't come up with a clear answer to "what's the point" in your case, then you shouldn't create a "master" class.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that you can not unit test the `main()` function itself. If you want to maximise your unit test coverage, you therefore must minimse your `main90` function. It might be argued that delegating to a function that you can unit test, rather than a `Master` class, might be better.

Comment: true and true. :) But I'd argue that in many cases, `main` can be kept so simple that there is little need to unit test it. And if it can't be kept that simple, then it is to complex anyway. (But yeah, I'm aware that some purists will insist on 100% test coverage, and then `main` can't possibly be more than single line of code (and even that would bring you below 100% coverage, strictly speaking)

Comment: does it make any sense to "unit test" the main function? if anything I would see it more as functional testing or something.

Answer (score 7):

You are describing two "extreme" approaches, neither of which sounds right to me. Neither having a single [God Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), nor having a single God Function is the right way to implement any nontrivial program intended for real use.

It can be OK to have a single call to `MasterClass` within your `main()` (although I would prefer partitioning functionality better, e.g. doing any command line-specific processing in `main()`, to decouple `MasterClass` from the details of command line parameters). However, if that class is hard to unit test, it is a sign of a design problem, and usually the solution is to delegate part or all of its testable functionality to other classes where it can be easily unit tested in separation, via public interfaces.

Your second approach can again be problematic to unit test, so you should strive to [extract methods](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) from it (and then preferably [move them into a separate class](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/moveMethod.html)) to make fine grained unit tests possible.

The sweet spot where you want to be is thus somewhere between the two extremes, constrained by the requirement of making your code testable.

It is worth thinking about how to structure your programs in general, not just in context of `main()`. The basic idea is to partition it into "chunks" (classes and methods) which are

- small enough to be understood, tested and maintained easily,
- logically cohesive.

Comment: I disagree. There has to be an entry point- whether it's a God function or a God class, there has to be at least one.

Comment: @DeadMG, of course. But quoting the OP: *"writing some unit test for the first approach [...] is a little difficult since most of the methods are private."*. This I interpret so that his `Master` class is a God Class, not delegating anything to anywhere.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean there. Yes, I completely agree.

Answer (score 3):

I would do the analysis of the arguments of the process in the main routine, then create a class instance by passing more readable parameters than argc and argv.

Answer (score 3):

First of: I rarely use C++, but I assume this is not really a language specific issue.
Well, I guess this boils down to taste aside from some practicality issues.
I personally tend to use layout #1, but don't put the commandline parsing routines in the *MasterClass*. For me, that clearly  belongs into the main. The *MasterClass* should get the *parsed* arguments (integers, FileStreams, whatever).

Answer (score 3):

Usually I call a main function (whith the same signature) in my application's namespace:

```
namespace current_application {
    int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
        // ...
    }
}
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    return current_application::main( argc, argv );
}
```

And then I usually use my actual main (the one in the namespace) to initialize *application wise* things:

- set locales on standard input/output/error)
- parse application parameters
- instantiate on object of my main class, if present (the equivalent of something like `QApplication`)
- call the main function, if present (the equivalent of something like `QApplication::run`)

and usually prefer to add a `try` `catch` block there in order to print more debugging info in case of crash.

---

All of this is highly subjective, however; it's part of your coding style.

Comment: I dont see what this gets you.  Except confused maintennance programmers. :)

Comment: Because you are trying to do something Java-ish in C++.  This kind of architecture, where you simply delgate `main()` to a free function within a namespace, doesn't *get* you anything, and is unexpected.  What does the namespaced `main` do for you that the non-namespaced one doesn't?

Comment: @John Dibling: my application main function logically belongs to my application namespace, so I think it's cleaner to put it there. Moreover by putting `main` in my namespace I can use symbols defined in the namespace without needing to explicit them (or to have a `using`-directive). At last this adds a further abstraction level: I've got a function outside my main, it often comes handy for quick hacks/tests, and it would easily let me use my application as a library: if I need to use most of the code for other projects, just get the whole thing and rewrite `::main` (this is popular in Python)

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach is very common, although the class tends to be named 'Application' (or at least contain the word 'Application') so do that.

Answer (score 1):

If an exception doesn't have a handler, then it's unspecified whether destructors of local objects are called before `std::terminate`.

If you want to make that behavior predictable, then `main` is a good place to have a top-most exception handler, with some kind of reporting.

Usually that's all that I put in `main`, which otherwise just calls a `cppMain`... ;-)

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Another trick is, instead of having objects at global scope, you can have pointers at global scope, and then construct the objects inside main (and thus control construction order) and set the pointers to point at those locals, and then call the "real" main function. Thus deterministic construction and destruction and ordering thereof :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I perform necessary platform-specific setup action and then delegate to an object.  There's little advantage of an object over a function, but objects can inherit from interfaces which is good if you have say platform-independent libraries that use interface implementation for callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The example you have given just moves the main function inside a namespace. I don't see the advantage here. A middle of the road approach with a slight tendency towards the Master Class model works for me. The Master Class object would usually be huge and best created on the heap. I have the main function create the the object and handle any errors that might occur here.

```
class MasterClass {
public:
static MasterClass* CreateInstance( int argc, char **argv );
    // ...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
         MasterClass mc = MC::CreateInstance(argc, argv);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This also has the advantage that any processing which does not have anything to do with the actual program logic, such as, reading the environment, etc does not have to be put in the MasterClass. They can go in main(). A good example is a server add-in task for the Lotus Domino system. Here the task should only run when control is handed over to it by the Domino scheduler task. Here the main will probably look as below:

```
STATUS LNPUBLIC AddInMain(HMODULE hModule, int argc, char far *argv[])
{
     MasterClass mc = MC::CreateInstance(argc, argv);
     while(/* wait for scheduler to give control */)
     {
          STATUS s = mc->RunForTimeSlice();
          if (s != SUCCESS)
               break;
     }
     // clean up
}
```

All the logic for interacting with the scheduler is thus in main and the rest of the program does not have to handle any of it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer an IOC (Inversion of Control) approach to my programs.

My "main" therefore uses the command arguments to determine the "options" and the "configuration" of the program. By options I mean interpreting certain flags passed in the command-line and by configuration I mean loading of configuration files.

The object it uses to load the configuration files then has a command to "run" but what is run (if anything) depends also on command-line arguments.